# My first applet won't load in browser

Tags: java, eclipse, browser, applet, windows-xp

I've been learning java for a while. I recently decided it's time to leave the simple console applications and start making applets. Everything is great so far except the fact that I can't find a way to run any applet made in eclipse on either of my browsers.
I downloaded [this example](http://www.roseindia.net/eclipse/applet-eclipse.shtml) to make sure everything is alright and it still renders the very same result when loaded in the browser.
When I open the html file the only thing in the tab is the border of the applet and the line "Error: click for details" top left. After I click the Java Console comes up and all that it says under the block of key instructions is:

> Detected from bootclasspath: C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jre7\lib\deploy.jar

I don't even know if this is any sort of error report or just a notification... after the console is cleared it won't come up again...

I tried with: IE 8 and Chromium 17 on winxp 32

[Applets on webpages](http://www.realapplets.com/tutorial/GuiExample.html) run fine.

Please help me! This makes me very sad. The fact that I don't know anything about JRE and whether it needs any further configuration after installation gives me hope that there might be a simple and trivial solution to my issue.

Comment: 1) (Generally) don't trust information from roseindia.net 2) What version SDK is being used to compile the code?  3) What do your browsers report for [these properties](http://pscode.org/prop/?prop=java.vendor.url%2Cjava.version%2Cjava.vm.specification.version%2Cjava.vm.version&format=TSV)? 4) I had some trouble with 1.7 JRE/SDKs and ended up removing it for the moment, until Java 7 becomes more robust.  It might be '1.7' that is the problem.

Comment: Name Value
java.vendor.url http://java.oracle.com/
java.version 1.7.0_01
java.vm.specification.version 1.7
java.vm.version 21.1-b02

>What version SDK is being used to compile the code? 
How do I get that?

Comment: *"I recently decided it's time to leave the simple console applications and start making applets"* That is not a logical progression.  It should be more like 1) console apps 2) [`JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) based GUI apps. 3) '2' + launched from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) 4) Adapting the frame to a hybrid application/applet so it can be embedded in a web app. and controlled using JavaScript. ..  **Note that applets are at stage 4, rather than 2.**  Applets are not easy to develop *or* deploy.

Comment: To get the compiler version, go to the command line and type `javac -version`.

Comment: Oh, I'm reading a starter book about java and everything is presented using console applications. The very last chapter of the book is about applets. This led me to think applets are the logical advancement... Are you saying that it is perfectly normal for me not to be able to run an applet in a browser? I thought this was some rare case related to my system.

Comment: *"Are you saying that it is perfectly normal for me not to be able to run an applet in a browser?"*  For a developer that is experienced at deploying frame based GUIs?  Yes.  For someone who has not done even that much?  Certainly.  See also paras. 3 & 4 under **Java Applets** at the [applet info.](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info) page here at SO (where I expand on that concept).

Comment: Thank You for the help!
It seems that it works fine when I export the project to a .jar file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not too sure what your issue is right now.  That's not an error report, just saying that `deploy.jar`, from the JRE, is being used.

When you say the example "renders the very same result" what result is that?
Can you properly run the "this example" you posted?

Are you compiling the project properly into a jar?
Are those jars in the same directory?

Comment: No I didn't compile the project into jar. That was the problem! Thanks!